# List item отображает строку не полностью

Tags: java, android, listview, android-layout

У меня есть `listview` с информацией  заполняемой пользователем. Мне нужно чтоб каждый `item` мог быть выбран. Но если я указываю в качестве разметки `R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice`, то строки отображаются не полностью. При этом если в качестве разметки использовать `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` ,то строки будут видны полностью.
Есть ли какой-то метод или `layout` который это поправит? Или только использование кастомных списков?

[image: <code>R.layout.simple_list_item_1</code>]
[image: <code>R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice</code>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так выглядит R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd" />
```

А вот так R.layout.simple_list_item_1:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

Как вы можете заметить, в первом случае высота ограничена параметром

`?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall`

Т.е. **чтобы решить ваш вопрос**, достаточно просто написать свою разметку с таким же кодом, но без ограничения по высоте.